# Display query to combine rows in the same database table based on a condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to display the result of below query based on condition, the condition is to display the Module column with status, ie if Any of the Module Test case has Failed, show Module, Status (Application, Fail), if all the Module Test case have passed, show Module, Status (Application, Pass).

The Group query will look like:

[image: Group Query]

The query i have written to show the above result:

```
SELECT ModuleID,status 
FROM [dbo].[ReportCollectionSGI]
GROUP BY ModuleID, status
ORDER BY ModuleID, status
```

The output display query required:

[image]

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3):

You need some conditional logic:

```
SELECT ModuleID,
       (CASE WHEN MIN(status) = MAX(status) AND
                  MIN(status) = 'Passed'
             THEN 'Passed'
             ELSE 'Failed'
        END) as status
FROM [dbo].[ReportCollectionSGI]
GROUP BY ModuleID
ORDER BY ModuleID;
```

In this particular case with two statuses, you can also just use `MIN()`:

```
SELECT ModuleID,
       MIN(status) as status
FROM [dbo].[ReportCollectionSGI]
GROUP BY ModuleID
ORDER BY ModuleID;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try like below

```
SELECT case when count(distinct status) = 1 and max(status)='Passed'
 then 'Passed'     
 else 'Failed' 
FROM [dbo].[ReportCollectionSGI] t
```

when all the `status` is passed then distinct count will be 1 and `max(status`) also will be passed